# How to use try-catch block for PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch

What is a decent way to handle PDO error when using try catch block?

Currently I have something like this:

**BlogModel.php**

```
   class BlogModel extends Model {
       public function save($id, $value) {
         $stmt = $this->getDb()->prepare('UPDATE setting SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');
         $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
         $stmt->bindParam(':name', $values);
         return ($stmt->execute() !== false) ? $id : false;
       }
   }
```

So, in the controller **BlogController.php**, I would do something like this:

```
<?php
class Blog extends Controller {

    public function comments()
    {
        $data = array();
        $model = new BlogModel;

        if ($model->save(2,'test')) {
                $data['result']['message'] = 'Settings saved';
                $data['result']['status'] = 'success';
        } else {
                $data['result']['message'] = 'Could not save the settings';
                $data['result']['status'] = 'error';
        }

        $view = new View("view.php", $data)
        $view->render();
    }
}
?>
```

This is the way I handle PDO error using `if` conditions. What is the decent way to translate this into try catch block?  I don't want to code the variables (`$data['result']['message']` `$data['result']['status']`) all the time.

Is possible to add "throw exception" in the catch block somehow?

If there is a lot of try catch blocks in the controller, it going to look messy.. right?

Comment: Just curious: Is this CakePHP? I can't tell.

Comment: @SimpleCoder my own MVC I have written ;)

Comment: Oh, neat. I guess the direct use of PDO should have given that away, as opposed to Cake's db interface.

Comment: You may find this page of the PHP docs useful http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: Have a look at the [example here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#99518). You can cut out all the useless html but you get the gist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the answers here are wrong. But actually all three combined are the real answer.
You should definitely set

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

as said by **Cerad**.

From now on every single issue about anything regarding database is thrown via exception of type `PDOException`. You just don't have to throw your own `Exception` as said by **ladar** because it's useless. Just take the **ladar** code and convert it into

```
 ...
 $data = array();
 $model = new BlogModel;

    try{
      $model->save(2,'test');
      $data['result']['message'] = 'Settings saved';
      $data['result']['status'] = 'success';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $data['result']['message'] = 'Could not save the settings';
        $data['result']['status'] = 'error';
    }
```

And do NOT throw anything by yourself.

Then a very nice way for debugging PDO queries is using the catch script linked by **Basic** that you can find [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#99518) once again.

Combining this things togheter you'll have a flexible, clean and easy-debug way to catch all the errors that could come.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
class BlogModel extends Model {
   public function save($id, $value) {
   ...
   if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        throw new Exception($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
   return $id;
```

And then

```
 ...
 $data = array();
 $model = new BlogModel;

    try{
      $model->save(2,'test');
      $data['result']['message'] = 'Settings saved';
      $data['result']['status'] = 'success';
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $data['result']['message'] = 'Could not save the settings';
        $data['result']['status'] = 'error';
    }
```

Comment: +1 for actually showing an example and not just providing a link to something else

Comment: Not a bad example, thanks.. Is there alternative way to that?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered letting PDO itself throw exceptions instead of errors?

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now you can eliminate checking PDO errors which can significantly reduce code.  You can add some try/catch block to catch exceptions that can be recovered from such as constraint violations.

For the rest just use a Try/Catch somewhere high up in your front end controller to catch the truly exceptional exceptions.

The only difference in my approach is that in BlogModel you just:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

No checking or anything else.  Just let PDO throw an exception if the insert fails.  Then you would use the try/catch in your controller [as shown by ladar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252276/how-to-use-try-catch-block-for-pdo/9252439#9252439)

Or in my case, if I was pretty sure the insert would never fail then I'd just use a generic try/catch block up in my front controller and not spend time trying to handle each possible exception manually.

Comment: Kind of a general request.  Do you understand how to tell PDO to throw exceptions instead of generating errors?  Basically use the setAttribute method I showed in my answer.  And do you understand that once PDO is throwing exceptions there will no longer be a need to check errors from things like: $stmt->execute();